# Insert Grails Domain object with foreign key

Tags: grails, model-view-controller, groovy, grails-orm

I have two domain classes :

```
class User {
Client client
String firstName
String lastName
String email
String password
String address
String city
String state
String zip
String phone
Integer active
Date changedate

static belongsTo = [client : Client]

static constraints = {
    firstName(nullable: false, blank:false)
    lastName(nullable: false, blank:false)
    email(nullable: false, blank: false)
    address(nullable:false,blank:false)
    city(nullable:false,blank:false)
    state(nullable:false,blank:false)
    zip(nullable:false,blank:false)
    phone(nullable:false,blank:false)
    active(nullable:false,blank:false)
    changedate(nullable:false,blank:false)
}
```

}

```
class Client {
String name
String webaddress
String address
String city
String state
String zip
String phone
Integer active
Date changedate

static constraints = {
    name(unique:true, nullable: false, blank:false)
    address(nullable:false,blank:false)
    city(nullable:false,blank:false)
    state(nullable:false,blank:false)
    zip(nullable:false,blank:false)
    phone(nullable:false,blank:false)
    active(nullable:false,blank:false)
    changedate(nullable:false,blank:false)
}
```

}

Now the two tables are generated and a foreign key exists from user to client.  I cannot for the life of me despite reading the grails help docs figure out how to insert a user record with a corresponding client.  This is the current code in my controller.  The client inserts correctly but will not insert the user record.

```
def register(){

    Client newClient = new Client (
        name: params.Company,
        webaddress: params.WebAddress,
        address: params.CompanyAddress,
        city: params.CompanyCity,
        state: params.CompanyState,
        zip: params.CompanyZip,
        phone: params.CompanyPhone,
        active: 1,
        changedate: new Date()          
    )
    newClient.save()
    User user =  new User (
        client: newClient,
        firstName: params.FirstName,
        lastName: params.LastName,
        email: params.userName,
        password: params.Password,
        address: params.Address,
        city: params.City,
        state: params.State,
        zip: params.Zip,
        phone: params.Phone,
        active: 1,
        changedate: new Date()
    )
    user.save()

}
```

Comment: The code looks fine.  You haven't provided enough info to say for sure but it may be that validation is failing when you save the user.  Try `user.save(failOnError: true)` or print `user.errors` after invoking `user.save()`.

Comment: `params.userName` is a suspect.  The common thing would be for your request parameter names to begin with a lower case letter but since all of the others begin with an upper case letter I am suspicious that the actual parameter name might be `UserName` in which case `params.userName` would evaluate to null.  Since you are assigning that to the `email` property which is not nullable, if `params.userName` were null that would explain the problem.

Comment: Eek, userName did indeed have an uppercase U as well as password with a P.   Sometimes you let the frustration of learning a new language make you forget the basics of coding.  Thanks for the help guys, the user was just inserted.  I feel silly.

Comment: FYI... In real application code you should be checking the return value when you call `save()`.  If validators fail, the `save()` method returns null.  `if(user.save()) { // success } else { // error }`.

Comment: Thank you, that's helpful.  Coming from a c# background grails and java in general is a learning process.  Just trying to get things to work before error handling is taken into account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code it will point out where exactly the validation problem is while saving the object to db if any :

```
def register(){

    Client newClient = new Client (
            name: params.Company,
            webaddress: params.WebAddress,
            address: params.CompanyAddress,
            city: params.CompanyCity,
            state: params.CompanyState,
            zip: params.CompanyZip,
            phone: params.CompanyPhone,
            active: 1,
            changedate: new Date()
    )
    if(newClient.save(flush: true)){
        User user =  new User (
                client: newClient,
                firstName: params.FirstName,
                lastName: params.LastName,
                email: params.userName,
                password: params.Password,
                address: params.Address,
                city: params.City,
                state: params.State,
                zip: params.Zip,
                phone: params.Phone,
                active: 1,
                changedate: new Date()
        )
        if(!user.save(flush: true)){
            user.errors.each {
                println it
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        newClient.errors.each {
            println it
        }
    }
}
```